# Recording heading with magnetometer that is inside spinning object

Tags: sensor, imu, magnetometer

I'm wondering if it is possible to record the heading of an object (call it a ball) that has a 3 axis magnetometer in it? obviously if the ball was still it would be simple, but as the ball is spinning it makes it a lot more difficult.

I'm trying to get the heading direction of the object so I know which direction it is traveling in and if it is experiencing drift due to wind or other external conditions (such as the direction of spin).

Answer (score 2):

Nope.  You can't tell the direction of travel of a ball, with only the 3-axis magnetometer.  The magnetometer doesn't "see" the translational component.

Let's take a ball that can have a translational motion in any arbitrary direction, and can not spin at all.  The magnetometer inside of the ball will always give you the same reading, regardless of the direction the ball is traveling in.  So, it can't be used for detecting direction of travel.

*[Humiliating, isn't it?]*

Comment: You can however measure both attitude and translation (acceleration) with a combined magnetometer and accelerometer. There are challenges though....because of the rate (Radians/S) of change in signals you couldn't use for example an I2C interface (https://www.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/Magneto/LSM303%20Datasheet.pdf) you'd have to have direct A/D (parallel)conversion with potentially very high data rates.    This type IMU implementation also has an error rate (drift) that may make it impossible to track the device for more than a few 10's of seconds.

Comment: ....this is an example of a camera that uses an accelerometer to figure out when it's at the top of it's arc (a change from up to down acceleration) and take a picture: http://www.bbc.com/news/technology-25926300

Comment: @JackCreasey could you explain a little more why I2C wouldn't work? I have selected 2x stand alone accel. and magneto units to achieve high data rates (up to 800hz). I'm guessing it might have something to do with data transfer speed?

Comment: Successful use of I2C would depends on what speed your device will spin at, the resolution of your sensors (bits for both magnetometer and accelerometer) and the speed at which you can transfer data (bits/Second). While I2C can work up to 3+ Mhz, for many (based on microprocessor hardware and software loop times) limitations of either 100 kHz or 400 kHz may exist. This limits the number of readings per second you can take and process. for example the MPC3021 A/D converts in 9 uS but you can only read at about 11 ksps http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21805a.pdf

Comment: With combined sensors such as the LSM303 things are more complicated when you have to read/write to several addresses to acquire you readings. This write-up from Adafruit might help you: https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/lsm303-accelerometer-slash-compass-breakout.pdf